# Let $G$ be a group of order $p^2$ then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $ \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: group-theory

If $|G|=p^2$ then $G$ is abelian. Now, like $G$ is abelian for the Theorem of finitely generated abelian groups $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$, but I don't know if I can do this or what other way I have?

Comment: Something in your "by the thm. of fin. gen. ab. grp., $G\cong \Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p$"  went wrong, because $G$ is indeed abelian, the theorem of finitely generated et cetera is true, but $G\cong \Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p$ needs not be true (in fact, $\Bbb Z_{p^2}$ is an abelian group of order $p^2$ and $\Bbb Z_{p^2}\not\cong\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p$).